# Solving Diffierential Equation with Eigenvector Concept problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the differential equation $$dx = Bx$$  whether B is a $2 \times 2$ amtrix

The question first propose the solution of $x$ would equals to $$ x = ae^{\lambda t} + bte^{\lambda t} $$

The first part want us to show if  **b is the eigenvector of matrix B**, then the proposed solution is indeed true.

And the next part of want us to proof the solution is correct as long as **a satisfies  (B - $\lambda$ I )a = b**

Thank You very much if you can help me with this one !!

Comment: please edit your question to clarify it, find MathJax help here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Your question being?